# jquery <li> hover effect working on jsfiddle but not test site

Tags: jquery

i am working on a jquery `<li>` hover effect and it is working on jsfiddle but not on the test site ie the 'hidden' div is not being displayed on hover.

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/p4xXH/

both have the same resources, html and css and the only difference is that i have added opening and closing `<script>` tags around the js in the head area of the test site.

there are no errors in firebug.

is it ok to use all the js code from jsfiddle and just wrap `<script>` tags around it, or does this cause some syntax errors that could be preventing the hover effect from working?

here is the code i am using on the test site (no link available).

```
<script>
// begin hover functionality
$(".magic li").each(function() {

var hiddenDiv = $(this).find(".card"),
parentElement = $(this),
api = {};

api.isOpen = false;

api.timeout = null;

api.position = function(){
hiddenDiv.css({
"top": parentElement.offset().top - $("#non_scrollable_area").offset().top - 106,
"left": parentElement.offset().left - $("#non_scrollable_area").offset().left - 94 
});
}

api.resetTimeout = function(){

clearTimeout( api.timeout );
}

api.startShowing = function(){

api.resetTimeout();

api.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
api.show();        
},200);
}

api.startHiding = function(){

api.resetTimeout();

api.timeout = setTimeout(function(){
api.hide();        
},150);
}
api.show= function(){

if(!api.isOpen){

api.position();

hiddenDiv .fadeIn(300);

api.isOpen = true;

// $("#isotope_container").bind("scroll.hiddendiv",api.position);

}
}

api.hide = function(){

if( api.isOpen ) {
api.isOpen = false;
// $("#isotope_container").unbind("scroll.hiddendiv");     
hiddenDiv.fadeOut(100);
}

}

hiddenDiv.bind("mouseenter", function() {

api.resetTimeout();

}).bind("mouseleave", function() {

api.startHiding();

}).css("z-index", 100).appendTo("#non_scrollable_area"); 

$(this).data("hiddenApi",api );

}).bind("mouseenter", function() {

var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

api.startShowing();

}).bind("mouseleave", function() { // start closing timeout once mouse leaves isotope element

var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

api.startHiding();

});

// begin custom scrollbar
(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".holder_a, .holder_b, .holder_c, .holder_d").mCustomScrollbar({
set_width:false, 
set_height:false, 
horizontalScroll:true, 
scrollInertia:550, 
scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc", 
mouseWheel:"auto", 
autoDraggerLength:true, 
scrollButtons:{ 
enable:false, 
scrollType:"continuous", 
scrollSpeed:20, 
scrollAmount:40 
},
advanced:{
updateOnBrowserResize:true, 
updateOnContentResize:false, 
autoExpandHorizontalScroll:false, 
autoScrollOnFocus:true 
},
callbacks:{
onScrollStart:function(){}, 
onScroll:function(){}, 
onTotalScroll:function(){}, 
onTotalScrollBack:function(){}, 
onTotalScrollOffset:0, 
whileScrolling:false, 
whileScrollingInterval:30 
}
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: put everything in `$(document).ready(function(){--here--});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".magic li").each(function () {

    var hiddenDiv = $(this).find(".card"),
    parentElement = $(this),
    api = {};

    api.isOpen = false;

    api.timeout = null;

    api.position = function () {
        hiddenDiv.css({
            "top": parentElement.offset().top - $("#non_scrollable_area").offset().top - 106,
            "left": parentElement.offset().left - $("#non_scrollable_area").offset().left - 94
        });
    }

    api.resetTimeout = function () {

        clearTimeout(api.timeout);
    }

    api.startShowing = function () {

        api.resetTimeout();

        api.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            api.show();
        }, 200);
    }

    api.startHiding = function () {

        api.resetTimeout();

        api.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            api.hide();
        }, 150);
    }
    api.show = function () {

        if (!api.isOpen) {

            api.position();

            hiddenDiv.fadeIn(300);

            api.isOpen = true;

        // $("#isotope_container").bind("scroll.hiddendiv",api.position);

        }
    }

    api.hide = function () {

        if (api.isOpen) {
            api.isOpen = false;
            // $("#isotope_container").unbind("scroll.hiddendiv");     
            hiddenDiv.fadeOut(100);
        }

    }

    hiddenDiv.bind("mouseenter", function () {

        api.resetTimeout();

    }).bind("mouseleave", function () {

        api.startHiding();

    }).css("z-index", 100).appendTo("#non_scrollable_area");

    $(this).data("hiddenApi", api);

}).bind("mouseenter", function () {

    var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

    api.startShowing();

}).bind("mouseleave", function () { // start closing timeout once mouse leaves isotope element

    var api = $(this).data("hiddenApi");

    api.startHiding();

   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you, your comment suggestion worked ie ````put everything in $(document).ready(function(){--here--});````

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle the code has been included within an `onload` handler as per the drop-down on the left under "Framework". In your test site there is no `onload` handler. This is why they behave differently.

You need to either include the script at the *end* of your document (just before the closing `</body>` tag) or wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` handler.

If you put your script in the `<head>` without using document ready (or `onload` for oldschool non-jQuery code) then it can't access any elements because they haven't been parsed and added to the DOM yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( function() {

// All Your JS Code here

});
```

In JS Fiddle They Already Have `$(window).load( function() { });` but you don not have `$(document).ready( function() { });` or `$( function() { });` which is another way to add `$(document).ready( function() { });` event handler!

**Why Should I use that?**

**Ans:** It bind all event handler to the associated elements as soon as document is completely loaded. Other Events are also used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the first comment suggestion from @jai and it seems to have worked:

```
put everything in $(document).ready(function(){--here--});
```

thank you very much, that question must have been up for less than thirty seconds before it got several answers, thank you!